# JNLP Applet with custom DownloadServiceListener & Versioning

Tags: java, jsp, applet, jnlp, next-generation-plugin

I encountered a problem, when using a JNLP applet with custom DownloadServiceListener as well as versioned jar files at the same time.

The project structure is as follows:

```
/
+ WEB-INF/
|        + lib/
|        |    + jnlp-servlet.jar
|        + web.xml
+ lib/
|    + progress-0.1.jar
|    + MyApplet-1.0.jar
|    + applet.jnlp
|    + version.xml
+ index.jsp
```

The contents of my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">

    <!-- JNLP download servlet-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jnlp.sample.servlet.JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/lib/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My applet.jnlp file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="$$codebase" href="$$name">
    <information>
        <title>MyApplet</title>
        <vendor>My AG</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.nowhere.com"/>
        <description>XYZ</description>
    </information>
    <update check="always" policy="always"/>
    <resources>
        <j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="128m"/>
        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>

    <jar href="progress.jar" version="0.1" download="progress"/>
    <jar href="MyApplet.jar" version="1.0" main="true"/>

    </resources>
    <applet-desc name="MyApplet"
                 main-class="test.MyApplet"
                 width="800" height="600"
                 progress-class="progress.CustomProgress">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="28,28,28"/>
        <param name="textcolor" value="255,222,123"/>
    </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

To display the applet, I use the following JSP-File (index.jsp):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head><title>Simple jsp page</title></head>
  <body style="margin: 0;">

    <object width="100%" vspace="0" hspace="0" height="100%" align="top" name="MyApplet"
            classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-0026-ABCDEFFEDCBA" onerror="alert('Invalid Java Version..')">
        <param value="MyApplet" name="name">
        <param value="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.6.0_26" name="type">
        <param value="test.MyApplet.class" name="code">
        <param value="lib/MyApplet-1.0.jar" name="archive">
        <param value="true" name="mayscript">
        <param value="false" name="scriptable">
        <param value="lib/applet.jnlp" name="jnlp_href">
        <param value="true" name="progressbar">
        <param value="238,244,248" name="boxbgcolor">
        <param value="255,255,255" name="boxfgcolor">
        <param value="255,255,227" name="progresscolor">
        <param value="Loading MyApplet - please wait" name="boxmessage">
        <param value="-Djnlp.versionEnabled=true -Xms256m -Xmx256m" name="java_arguments">
        <param value="false" name="classloader_cache">
        <param value="true" name="separate_jvm">
        <comment>
            <embed width="100%" vspace="0" hspace="0" height="100%" align="top" separate_jvm="true"
                   classloader_cache="false" java_arguments="-Djnlp.packEnabled -Xms256m -Xmx256m"
                   boxmessage="Loading MyApplet - please wait" boxfgcolor="255,255,255"
                   boxbgcolor="238,244,248" progressbar="true"
                   pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/index.html#download"
                   jnlp_href="lib/applet.jnlp" scriptable="false" mayscript="true"
                   archive="lib/MyApplet-1.0.jar" code="test.MyApplet.class"
                   type="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.6.0_26"
                   name="MyApplet" onerror="alert('Invalid Java version')">
        </comment>
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

And the file for the version mapping (version.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jnlp-versions>
  <resource>
    <pattern>
      <name>MyApplet.jar</name>
      <version-id>1.0</version-id>
    </pattern>
    <file>MyApplet-1.0.jar</file>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <pattern>
      <name>progress.jar</name>
      <version-id>0.1</version-id>
    </pattern>
    <file>progress-0.1.jar</file>
  </resource>
</jnlp-versions>
```

The implementation of the DownloadServiceListener (which is +/- an exact copy of the Sun (or Oracle) example (except that no image is used):

```
package progress;

import javax.jnlp.DownloadServiceListener;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.applet.AppletStub;

public class CustomProgress implements DownloadServiceListener {
    Container surfaceContainer = null;
    AppletStub appletStub = null;
    JProgressBar progressBar = null;
    JLabel statusLabel = null;
    boolean uiCreated = false;

    public CustomProgress(Object surface) {
       init(surface, null);
    }

    public CustomProgress(Object surface, Object stub) {
        init(surface, stub);
    }

    public void init(Object surface, Object stub) {
        try {
            surfaceContainer = (Container) surface;
            appletStub = (AppletStub) stub;
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            cce.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void downloadFailed(java.net.URL url, java.lang.String version) {        
    }

    public void progress(URL url, String version, long readSoFar, long total, int overallPercent) {
        // check progress of download and update display
        updateProgressUI(overallPercent);

    }

    public void upgradingArchive(java.net.URL url, java.lang.String version, int patchPercent, int overallPercent) {
        updateProgressUI(overallPercent);
    }

    public  void validating(java.net.URL url, java.lang.String version, long entry, long total, int overallPercent) {
        updateProgressUI(overallPercent);
    }

    private void updateProgressUI(int overallPercent) {
        if (!uiCreated && overallPercent > 0 && overallPercent < 100) {
            // create custom progress indicator's UI only if 
            // there is more work to do, meaning overallPercent > 0 and < 100
            // this prevents flashing when RIA is loaded from cache
            create(); 
            uiCreated = true;            
        }
        if (uiCreated) {
            progressBar.setValue(overallPercent);
        }
    }

    private void create() {
        JPanel top = createComponents();
        if (surfaceContainer != null) {
            // lay out the loading progress indicator UI in the given Container
            surfaceContainer.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            surfaceContainer.invalidate();
            surfaceContainer.validate();
        }
    }

    private JPanel createComponents() {
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        top.setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));

        // get applet parameter using an instance of the AppletStub class
        // "tagLine" parameter specified in applet's JNLP file
        String tagLine = "";
        if (appletStub != null) {
            tagLine = appletStub.getParameter("tagLine");
        }
        String lblText = "<html><font color=red size=+2>JDK Documentation</font><br/>" +
                            tagLine + " <br/></html>";
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(lblText);
        top.add(lbl, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // use JSObject.getWindow(null) method to retrieve a reference to
        // the web page and make JavaScript calls. Duke logo displayed if
        // displayLogo variable set to "true" in the web page
//        String displayLogo = "true";
//        if (displayLogo.equals("true")) {
//            lbl = new JLabel();
//            ImageIcon logo = createImageIcon("images/DukeWave.gif", "logo");
//            lbl.setIcon(logo);
//            top.add(lbl, BorderLayout.EAST);
//        }

        statusLabel = new JLabel("<html><font color=green size=-2>Loading applet...</font></html>");
        top.add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        top.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return top;
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = CustomProgress.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And last but not least, my (very basic) applet:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyApplet extends JApplet {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        add(new JLabel("This is an applet .. "));
    }
}
```

As you can see, everything is kept as simple as possible.. :)

Now, if I deploy the web application, and then access the file index.jsp, the following happens:
There are two java consoles available, one for the "DownloadServiceListener", and another for the "real" applet.
On the first, one can find the following message:

> Error generating custom progress : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   progress.CustomProgress

The second console is empty, and the applet is correctly displayed, showing the text: "This is an applet ..".

There are the following entries in my access-log:
(Note that the whole java cache has been cleared before every test).

```
24/08/2011:14:57:09 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/ HTTP/1.1' 200 - 24/08/2011:14:57:09 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:12 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/applet.jnlp HTTP/1.1' 200 1041 24/08/2011:14:57:12 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/MyApplet__V1.0.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/progress__V0.1.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/progress.jar?version-id=0.1 HTTP/1.1' 200 3987 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/MyApplet.jar?version-id=1.0 HTTP/1.1' 200 2460484 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/progress.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/progress.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/MyApplet.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/MyApplet.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/progress.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/progress.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/MyApplet.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/MyApplet.jar HTTP/1.1' 404 - 24/08/2011:14:57:13 +0200
127.0.0.1 24/08/2011:14:57:14 +0200 'GET /AppletTest/lib/applet.jnlp HTTP/1.1' 304 - 24/08/2011:14:57:14 +0200
```

When I look in the "Java Control Panel", the applet "MyApplet" appears, and all jar-files were loaded as expected.

When I remove the "jnlp.versionEnabled"-property, skip the version parameters of the jar-entries, and add the version number to the jar-file-names, then the custom DownloadServiceListener works perfectly.

Is it possible, that the two things (versioned jar-files & custom DSL) can not be used together?
Did I miss something? Any ideas?

Comment: Well that's a whole heapin' helpin' of question!  I have not read it all, but glancing over the JNLP it seems to be invalid.  Try using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) to validate the JNLP directly as it comes off the server (so the codebase etc. is resolved).

Comment: JaNeLA obviously does not know about the new java 1.6 update 21 features.. :(

Comment: The new features are described on the following page: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/customProgressIndicatorForApplet.html

Comment: Do you know of an updated DTD that includes those attributes?  JaNeLA uses an XSD that is (or at least was) initially generated from the DTD.  BTW - the 2 things I noted were fields (possibly) out of the correct order, and the missing [documentBase](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/syntax.html#applet_desc).

Comment: Sorry, I've never seen an (official) DTD for JNLP-files. Is the documentBase required? I'll give it a try .. thanks! Fields out of the correct order? The jar-element entries?

Comment: *"Fields out of the correct order? The jar-element entries?"*  I am sure it is mentioned in the JaNeLA ouput.  What parts of the output do you have, but are either ignoring or not understanding?  BTW - the validation document used is [JNLP-6.0.xsd](http://pscode.org/JNLP-6.0.xsd).